# How can set header once for all request that will be made in tauri

Tags: rust, header, desktop-application, tauri

in electron i could set the token to be used for all request going to a specific service like so

```js
import { session } from 'electron'
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders((details, callback) => {
    // set custom User-Agent in requestHeaders
    details.requestHeaders['User-Agent'] = `userAgent ${app.getVersion()}`
    // set custom Authorization header with access_token
    try {
      const url = new URL(store.get('login.server'))
      if (
        details.url.startsWith(url) &&
        store.get('login.access_token') !== ''
      ) {
        details.requestHeaders['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${store.get(
          'login.access_token'
        )}`
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // do nothing
    }
```

please how can i do this in tauri

i tried setting the access_token for every request i made using superagent, but its becoming complicated unlike when i was using electron